# different behavior when using re.finditer and re.match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.5

I'm working on a regex to to collect some values from a page through some script. I'm using `re.match` in condition but it returns false but if i use `finditer` it returns true and body of condition is executed. i tested that regex in my own built tester and it's working there but not in script.
here is sample script.

```
result = []
RE_Add0 = re.compile("\d{5}(?:(?:-| |)\d{4})?", re.IGNORECASE)
each = ''Expiration Date:\n05/31/1996\nBusiness Address: 23901 CALABASAS ROAD #2000 CALABASAS, CA 91302\n'
if RE_Add0.match(each):
    result0 = RE_Add0.match(each).group(0)
    print result0
    if len(result0) < 100:
        result.append(result0)
    else:
        print 'Address ignore'
else:
    None
```

Answer (score 3):

`re.finditer()` returns an iterator object even if there is no match (so an `if RE_Add0.finditer(each)` would always return `True`). You have to actually iterate over the object to see if there are actual matches.

Then, `re.match()` only matches at the beginning of the string, not anywhere in the string as `re.search()` or `re.finditer()` do.

Third, that regex could be written as `r"\d{5}(?:[ -]?\d{4})"`.

Fourth, always use raw strings with regexes.

Answer (score 2):

[`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) matches at the beginning of a string only once. `re.finditer` is similar to `re.search` in this regard, i.e., it matches iteratively. Compare:

```
>>> re.match('a', 'abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01057AA0>
>>> re.match('b', 'abc')
>>> re.finditer('a', 'abc')
<callable_iterator object at 0x0106AD30>
>>> re.finditer('b', 'abc')
<callable_iterator object at 0x0106EA10>
```

ETA: Since you're mentioning *page*, I can only surmise that you're talking about html parsing, if that is the case, use BeautifulSoup or a similar html parser. Don't use regex.

Comment: then could you help me how to get execute this script. i m stuck on for last 6 hours. no solution found :-( unfortunately i m not a good programmer :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

postalCode = re.compile(r'((\d{5})([ -])?(\d{4})?(\s*))$')
primaryGroup = lambda x: x[1]

sampleStr = """
    Expiration Date:
    05/31/1996
    Business Address: 23901 CALABASAS ROAD #2000 CALABASAS, CA 91302  
"""
result = []

matches = list(re.findall(postalCode, sampleStr))
if matches:
    for n,match in enumerate(matches): 
        pc = primaryGroup(match)
        print pc
        result.append(pc)
else:
    print "No postal code found in this string"
```

This returns '12345' on any of

```
12345\n
12345  \n
12345 6789\n
12345 6789    \n
12345 \n
12345     \n
12345-6789\n
12345-6789    \n
12345-\n
12345-    \n
123456789\n
123456789    \n
12345\n
12345    \n
```

I have it matching only at the end of a line, because otherwise it was also matching '23901' (from the street address) in your example.