# In python, how to 'if finditer(...) has no matches'?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to do something when finditer() does not find anything.

```
import re
pattern = "1"
string = "abc"  
matched_iter = re.finditer(pattern, string)
# <if matched_iter is empty (no matched found>.
#   do something.
# else
    for m in matched_iter:
        print m.group()
```

The best thing I could come up with is to keep track of found manually:

```
mi_no_find = re.finditer(r'\w+',"$$%%%%")   # not matching.
found = False
for m in mi_no_find:
    print m.group()
    found = True
if not found:
    print "Nothing found"
```

Related posts that don't answer:

- Counting finditer matches: [Number of regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895646/number-of-regex-matches) (I don't need to count, I just need to know if there are no matches).
- finditer vs match: [different behavior when using re.finditer and re.match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646904/different-behavior-when-using-re-finditer-and-re-match) (says always have to loop over an iterator returned by finditer)

[edit]
- I have no interest in enumerating or counting total output. Only if found else not found actions.
- I understand I can put finditer into a list, but this would be inefficient for large strings. One objective is to have low memory utilization.

Comment: If it is an iterator, you must iterate over it to know that it is empty. Unless the regex library adds a flourish, you'd end up having to do something like this, and this is reasonable enough to me

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/pnI5nq. Turn the iterable value into a list and you may easily use it for any further manipulations. Another way: if `if re.search(pattern, s):` then there is a match. See https://ideone.com/tw5jmf

Comment: Just turn it into a list: `list(re.finditer(pattern, string))`  If you don't have a ton of matches you won't notice a difference in performance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Updated 04/10/2020

Use `re.search(pattern, string)` to check if a pattern exists.

```
pattern = "1"
string = "abc"

if re.search(pattern, string) is None:
    print('do this because nothing was found')
```

Returns:

```
do this because nothing was found
```

If you want *to iterate over the return*, then place the `re.finditer()` within the `re.search()`.

```
pattern = '[A-Za-z]'
string = "abc"

if re.search(pattern, string) is not None:
    for thing in re.finditer(pattern, string):
        print('Found this thing: ' + thing[0])
```

Returns:

```
Found this thing: a
Found this thing: b
Found this thing: c
```

**Therefore, if you wanted both options, use the `else:` clause with the `if re.search()` conditional.**

```
pattern = "1"
string = "abc"

if re.search(pattern, string) is not None:
    for thing in re.finditer(pattern, string):
        print('Found this thing: ' + thing[0])
else:
    print('do this because nothing was found')
```

Returns:

```
do this because nothing was found
```

## previous reply below (not sufficient, just read above)

If the .finditer() does not match a pattern, then it will not perform any commands within the related loop.

So:

- Set the variable **before the loop** you are using to iterate over the regex returns
- Call the variable **after (And outside of)** the loop you are using to iterate over the regex returns

This way, if nothing is returned from the regex call, the loop won't execute and your variable call after the loop will return the exact same variable it was set to.

Below, example 1 demonstrates the regex finding the pattern. Example 2 shows the regex not finding the pattern, so the variable within the loop is never set. 
***Example 3*** shows my suggestion - where the variable is set before the regex loop, so if the regex does not find a match (and subsequently, does not trigger the loop), the variable call after the loop returns the initial variable set (Confirming the regex pattern was not found).

Remember to import the **import re** module.

EXAMPLE 1 (Searching for the characters 'he' in the string 'hello world' will return 'he')

```
my_string = 'hello world'
pat = '(he)'
regex = re.finditer(pat,my_string)

for a in regex:
    b = str(a.groups()[0])
print(b)

# returns 'he'
```

EXAMPLE 2 (Searching for the characters 'ab' in the string 'hello world' do not match anything, so the 'for a in regex:' loop does not execute and does not assign the b variable any value.)

```
my_string = 'hello world'
pat = '(ab)'
regex = re.finditer(pat,my_string)

for a in regex:
    b = str(a.groups()[0])
print(b)

# no return
```

EXAMPLE 3 (Searching for the characters 'ab' again, but this time setting the variable b to 'CAKE' before the loop, and calling the variable b after, outside of the loop returns the initial variable - i.e. 'CAKE' - since the loop did not execute).

```
my_string = 'hello world'
pat = '(ab)'
regex = re.finditer(pat,my_string)

b = 'CAKE' # sets the variable prior to the for loop
for a in regex:
    b = str(a.groups()[0])
print(b) # calls the variable after (and outside) the loop

# returns 'CAKE'
```

It's also worth noting that when designing your pattern to feed into the regex, make sure to use the parenthesis to indicate the start and end of a group.

```
pattern = '(ab)' # use this
pattern = 'ab' # avoid using this
```

**To tie back to the initial question:**

Since nothing found won’t execute the for loop (for a in regex), the user can preload the variable, then check it after the for loop for the original loaded value. This will allow for the user to know if nothing was found.

```
my_string = 'hello world'
pat = '(ab)'
regex = re.finditer(pat,my_string)

b = 'CAKE' # sets the variable prior to the for loop
for a in regex:
    b = str(a.groups()[0])
if b == ‘CAKE’:
    # action taken if nothing is returned
```

Comment: I think this kinda misses the point. The question was how to do the 'if nothing found' case.

Comment: @Leo Ufimtsev That’s fair. When .finditer() finds nothing, it bypasses the subsequent conditional code within the for loop (since there is no, ‘for a in...).

When the user preloads the variable, it is never replaced during the ‘for loop.’ So afrer the loop the user can check the variable for the preloaded value to test if nothing happened.

I need to supplement my answer!

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev Check out my update using re.search() and either 'is None' or 'is not None' to build a better suggestion. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I admire your persistence. I think this should be rewarded. This is indeed a good solution. marked as accepted answer. Thx for your input.

Comment: But wouldn't the regex be extecuted *twice*? If you're, for example, using this to manipulate live input wouldn't this be too much of a penalty?

Comment: @rafark good question. Yes. If programmer knows the pattern will rarely fail, then computationally the ‘if’ check is expensive. Instead, a, ‘try…except…’ clause can be used. This way, the additional computation is reserved for only those rare cases. It will require more evaluation to handle errors since ‘try…except’ responds to any errors (not specifically to the none case). If the none case is expected regularly, or if our goal is to evaluate the none case primarily, then the ‘if x is none’ approach might still be better.

Answer (score 4):

If performance isn't an issue, simply use `findall` or `list(finditer(...))`, which returns a list.

Otherwise, you can "peek" into the generator with `next`, then loop as normal if it raises `StopIteration`. Though there are other ways to do it, this is the simplest to me:

```
import itertools
import re

pattern = "1"
string = "abc"  
matched_iter = re.finditer(pattern, string)

try:
    first_match = next(matched_iter)
except StopIteration:
    print("No match!") # action for no match
else:
    for m in itertools.chain([first_match], matched_iter):
        print(m.group())
```

Answer (score 4):

You can probe the iterator with `next` and then `chain` the results back together while excepting `StopIteration` which means the iterator was empty:

```
import itertools as it

matches = iter([])
try:
    probe = next(matches)
except StopIteration:
    print('empty')
else:
    for m in it.chain([probe], matches):
        print(m)
```

Regarding your solution you could check `m` directly, setting it to `None` beforehand:

```
matches = iter([])
m = None
for m in matches:
    print(m)
if m is None:
    print('empty')
```

Comment: It would be safer to put only the `next` call in the `try`, and have the rest of the happy path in an `else`.

Comment: I like the m = None hack. It's simple enough that I can remember that during an interview. The try/catch kinda looks complicated to understand at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

It prints the original string if there are no matches in the string. 
It will replace the position `n` of the string.

For more reference: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

````
Input_Str = "FOOTBALL"

def replacing(Input_String, char_2_replace, replaced_char, n):
    pattern = re.compile(char_2_replace)
    if len(re.findall(pattern, Input_String)) >= n: 
        where = [m for m in pattern.finditer(Input_String)][n-1]
        before = Input_String[:where.start()]
        after = Input_String[where.end():]
        newString = before + replaced_char + after
    else: 
        newString = Input_String
    return newString

print(replacing(Input_Str, 'L', 'X', 4))```
````

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late, but very suitable for Python 3.8+

You can use the new [`warlus operator :=`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) operator along with [`next(iterator[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to solve for 'no matches' in [`re.finditer(pattern, string, flags=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) somewhat like this:

```py
import re

pattern_ = "1"
string_ = "abc" 

def is_match():
    was_found = False
    while next((match := re.finditer(pattern_, string_)), None) is not None:
        was_found = True
        yield match.group()  # or just print it
    return was_found
```